# Is it possible to insert records from one table to another table while doing a typecast?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say we have a table as

Table A

```
id  int  PK
firstname  varchar(50)
lastname   varchar(50)
dateOfBirth  varchar(10)
```

and need to insert them all using one SQL statement in Table B, however, table B is

```
id  int  PK
firstname  varchar(50)
lastname   varchar(50)
dateOfBirth  date
```

Question:

How can I use following statement while making dateOfBirth to go from varchar to date ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Just convert `dateOFbirth` to date before inserting. Be sure to use the correct format or you might be give an overflow error. For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
CONVERT(DATE, dateOfBirth, 101)
```

Comment: OK great! so I'm assuming if I want to have a DateTime format at the destination then have to concat them first then do this method. right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do both the conversion and insert in same statement:

Here is an example:

```
create table TableA
(
id  int not null Primary Key,
firstname  varchar(50) not null,
lastname   varchar(50) not null,
dateOfBirth  varchar(10) not null,
)

create table TableB
(
id  int not null Primary Key,
firstname  varchar(50) not null,
lastname   varchar(50) not null,
dateOfBirth  date not null,
)

insert into TableB values (1, 'firstName', 'lastname', '10/10/2014')

insert into tablea select id, firstname, lastname, CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofbirth, 101) from tableb
```